# What happens if NPM ever goes belly up?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

This is just out of curiosity, and partially out of my own dependence on the many packages NPM has to offer. What would happen if NPM were to suddenly shut down? Would all those thousands of NodeJS code bases that rely on NPM be SOL? Would there be any way to recover from something like that?

I realize answers to this question will mostly be speculation.

Comment: Well NPM has been bought by Github.  See [NPM has Joined GitHub](https://github.blog/2020-04-15-npm-has-joined-github/) and Github is owned by Microsoft.  The only way NPM shuts down is if it's been replaced by something better and nearly everyone has moved away from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `git clone` packages from GitHub, or develop your own modules.
If npm was becoming down, you technically couldn't download anything from him, but it wouldnt happened. NPM is supported by Microsoft.

Your previously downloaded locally stored packages would not disappear.

Comment: Oh haha, so I guess Microsoft would have to go belly up first. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: For sure! I tried a few minutes ago and it told me I had to wait.